# Porque este metodo me retorna una cantidad equivocada de matches?

Tags: java, regex

```
public int obtenerNumOraciones(String texto) {

    Pattern patron = Pattern.compile("[a-z]*");
    Matcher match = patron.matcher(texto);
    int cant = 0;
    while(match.find()){
        cant++;
    }

    return cant;
}
```

Si pongo texto=hola, este método me retorna 2, siendo que tiene que retornar un 1 , no entiendo porque retorna 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [a-z]* --> **Cero** o más ocurrencias de una letra.

El `matcher` empieza a procesar el *string*, se encuentra una letra y empieza a hacer el primer *match*.

Cuando se acaban las letras, lo que queda para seguir procesando es solo la cadena vacía.

Pero el problema es que tu expresión hace *match* con la cadena vacía, así que la marca como un nuevo *match*.

La solución más sencilla podría ser(dependiendo de lo que busques) usar `+` en vez de `*`; así la cadena vacía ya no es una expresión válida.

Puedes ver una demostración práctica aquí: https://ideone.com/FMkQc5